# Tesseract with 64-bit jvm

Tags: java, tesseract

I am using Tesseract with my application so i can extract the text from images.
This my code , everything is fine

```
public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String imagePath = "apps/Tess4J/eurotext.bmp";
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
        // Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But i realized that my .dll are for 32-bit jvm and we are using 64 instead. this is my error :
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found."

How should i work with this issue if i should stay with 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 32-bit native libraries from a 64-bit JVM (or vice versa). There are two possible solutions:

- Use a 32-bit JVM (this will work even if you have a 64-bit operating system)
- Use 64-bit versions of the native libraries you need to use

Note: You do not need to recompile your Java code. Java bytecode is independent of the "bitness" of the JVM and operating system.

Answer (score 0):

From your error the idea what I get is there is no logical linking for libtesseract302 is available. 
Following is the link for this error:

```
http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/a3e57163
```

and switch to 32 bit JVM,

Are you using Tess4J API ??? Or executing it using "tesseract" command?

I had the same problem to overcome it I executed the tesseract from commandline as shown below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tesseract " + fileName + " " + textFileName);
```

Comment: I am using Tess4J API under a web application. 
Plus libtesseract302 is under my Project root. Should i place it another place ?

Comment: There are methods in Tess4j to call, are you creating an instance of Tesseract class and then call the method doOCR(Image image) ??? I tried that I had the same error on 64 bit to overcome this what I did is I executed Tesseract from command line using Runtime, see my answer I updated it.

Comment: Yes i am using this method :
String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
Im going to try your solution using command line !

Comment: I tried your solution ! This is the error i've got: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\home\eclipse_workspace\TessHEAD\libtesseract302.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Comment: try executing directly from command line, give one image file and just type the name of the output file ... i.e : tesseract img.jpg textOutput. and tell me whether it runs or not... it looks like that you are not having tesseract in your path.